# Laravel - Jobs no se conectan a la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, jobs

Estoy usando Jobs encadenados en laravel, pero dejaron de funcionar y no sé qué pudo haber sido, iba 2 meses sin usarlos, en el log puedo ver que todos los problemas son problemas de conexión, comenzando con

```
    \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(638):
    Illuminate\Database\Connection->runQueryCallback('select `section...', Array, Object(Closure))
\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php(472): Illuminate\Database\Connection->run('insert into `gp...', Array, Object(Closure))
```

básicamente aquí empieza el problema que desencadena el resto de fallos.

En la consola no recibo ningún error, sin embargo, el primer Job que encadena al resto se repite y vuelve a intentarlo porque la base de datos rechazó la conexión, ¿dónde puedo verificar o configurar una conexión correcta de los Jobs con la base de datos?

El resto de mi aplicación funciona de forma totalmente normal.

Nota: Estoy corriendo todos los workers y sus colas

Nota 2: [Este es mi archivo](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/config/queue.php) config/queue.php **pero sin la línea 84**

en la tabla failed_jobs de la DB se me añade esto

```
Illuminate\Queue\MaxAttemptsExceededException: App\Jobs\GprInsight has been attempted too many times or run too long. The job may have previously timed out. in D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php:713
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(482): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->maxAttemptsExceededException(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob))
#1 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(396): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->markJobAsFailedIfAlreadyExceedsMaxAttempts('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 1)
#2 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(356): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#3 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(158): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#4 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(116): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'gmb', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#5 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(100): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'gmb')
#6 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(36): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->handle()
#7 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Util.php(40): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#8 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(93): Illuminate\Container\Util::unwrapIfClosure(Object(Closure))
#9 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(37): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#10 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(610): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#11 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(136): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#12 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command.php(255): Illuminate\Console\Command->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#13 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Command.php(121): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Illuminate\Console\OutputStyle))
#14 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(971): Illuminate\Console\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#15 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(290): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#16 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php(166): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#17 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Console\Application.php(93): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#18 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(129): Illuminate\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#19 D:\Programas\laragon\www\google-places-ranking\artisan(37): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 {main}
```

Comment: En teoría la conexión a la DB es global, por lo cual, si funciona en el resto de la aplicación igual debe funcionar en los jobs (A no ser que hayas echo algo raro por ahí para conectar a la DB o multiples DB).

¿Estás seguro que las tablas requeridas por los jobs existen en su totalidad? ¿Los datos que intentas insertar son validos y compatibles con la declaración de la tabla? Si lo referenciado en tu nota 2 es tu proyecto, no veo una migración para los jobs, solo para los fallidos.

Comment: hola @CésarAlejandroM no le he hecho ningún cambio a los jobs para que conecten a otras DB, simplemente empezaron a aparecer esos errores, lo de la nota es solamente un ejemplo, no es mi proyecto, quiero decir que el archivo queue está por defecto, sin cambios, las tablas están todas, como digo hace un mes funcionaba correctamente y no he eliminado ninguna tabla, tampoco les cambié la estructura

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM he actualizado mi pregunta incluyendo lo que aparece en la tabla de failed_jobs

Comment: Por la descripción del error vemos un ````MaxAttemptsExceededException```` y ````timed out````. La excepción de intentos puede pasar por el exceso de intentos que se vayan a time out, pero también puede ser alguna excepción que suceda dentro del código de tu job.

Intenta ejecutar el comando de los jobs asignando los siguientes parámetros````php artisan queue:listen --tries=3 --timeout=22000````

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM no entiendo por qué el job no deja de trabajar, yo creo que es porque no está conectando a la base de datos según el log de laravel, porque si pongo tries 3 el primer job se ejecuta 3 veces y no pasa al siguiente (hace 2 meses lo hacía)

Comment: Nos estamos yendo para otro lado, si ahora no obtienes el error inicial, entonces el problema fue solucionado aumentando el timeout del job (tiempo de ejecución) y por ende, todo lo nuevo cae en otra pregunta. ````--tries=3```` es la cantidad de intentos que se ejecutará un job en caso que falle o surja alguna excepción, el job siempre se ejecutará solo 1 vez a no ser que ingreses varias veces el mismo job a una queue, en ese caso el problema es otro. Respecto al largo tiempo de ejecución pueden ser muchos los factores.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119059/discussion-between-cesar-alejandro-m-and-andre-cuellar-avaroma).